# Different ways to calculate the bulk modulus

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, elasticity

I am trying to calculate the bulk modulus of unit cells of materials with  trigonal or monoclinic structure using two different methods:

-The first one is by fitting the changes of volume and energy to the Poirier-Tarantola equation of state.

$E\left(\varrho\right)=E_0 + \frac{B^{EOS}_0V_0\varrho^2}{6}\left(3+\varrho\left(B'_0-2\right)\right)$

-The second one consists on using the stiffness tensor.

$B_0=\frac{1}{9}\sum^3_{i,j}C_{ij}$

The results that I get are rather different (error of 15-20%).

The question is, are these two methods supposed to yield the same result?

PS. Some previous calculations on materials with cubic structure gave a good agreement between the two methods (error of ~1%)

Comment: How are your expressions taking account of the fact that your material is anisotropic?

Comment: @Floris  The first one deals with a volumetric expansion/contraction due to a hydrostatic pressure. The second one is a general expression for the calculation of the bulk modulus. No assumptions about structure/isotropy are made in any of them.

Comment: Could it be that hydrostatic pressure on a monoclinic structure can cause energy stored in the form of shear which is not accounted for in your first equation?

Comment: @Floris i do not know for sure. I hope some other user can shed some light on this matter.